# Windows 7 hangs once a day

Tags: windows-7, windows

I have a PC (Windows 7) that started hanging when I boot it up. It only does it once per 24 hours, usually about 5-10 minutes after loading Windows. When I force the reboot, everything works fine until the next day.

I look at the event logger, and nothing appears with the timestamp of the hang up (the significant last recorded event is usually the forced reboot).

It must be something that's on delayed start, but since I have no idea what it is, I'm not sure how to zero in on the problem.

Any ideas?
Thanks.

Comment: AutoReboot?  if you would like to see more you could turn that off.   Go to the Control Pannel, System, Advanced system settings, Advanced tab, in the System Failure section, make sure "[X] Write an event to the system log" is checked and uncheck "[ ] Automatic Restart". Usually this would give you a BSOD screen instead of drifting off without any info. The info of the crash can sometimes provide clues, it can also lead a person down the wrong path :-)  but it is something.

Comment: How do you force the reboot, and what exactly is hanging (does it just become sluggish? mouse/keyboard not responding? complete cpu halt? is there hard drive activity?)

Comment: Does the same thing happen on safe mode?

Comment: Everything just hangs, cursor will work for a few seconds, then freezes as well. Doesn't matter what is running (at first I thought it was a browser issue). I just reboot through the power button (there's no other way).

Comment: I will try safe mode (tomorrow LOL), but I do suspect it's some service that's causing the problem, so I imagine it won't happen in safe mode. Has the BSOD ever been helpful to anyone? I'm not an engineer (obviously), so those error messages are meaningless to me. I will try that, though. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Traced the problem, kind of. I disabled some non-vital events on the Task Scheduler which were set to daily with a delayed start. Solved the problem. I can't confirm it, because there were too many to test one by one (given that I could only replicate the issue once a day), but I suspect it was Google "phoning home" to check for updates, because I had fixed the problem, a few weeks later manually updated a Google product and the issue reappeared, I also noticed Google had set the task to check for updates again. In any case, problem seemed to be solved.

Answer (score 0):

I feel it is not a software issue. I suggest you physically inspect your machine , clean them and the reboot on safe mode. Also try booting at different times to check your 24 hr hanging problem. This will narrow down the point of the problem.

Comment: What do you mean by cleaning them?

Comment: I mean physically dusting them !

Comment: There doesn't seem to be anything wrong with the computer itself. Otherwise, it would just hang randomly. It's just once per day. After I force the reboot, it never hangs again, until I shut Windows down and, next day, reboot it. So I figure it's something that's loading up once a day (I thought maybe Windows update, but I ran the fixing utility and nothing).